# Multiple and single choice test

Tags: java, android

I am working on a Single choice and Multiple choice test.

I have couple of questions and 4 answers for each question.

I am shuffling the answers as each answer is assigned to radio button.
This is how i am shuffling the arraylist where Random is a arraylist with items and r1,r2,r3,r4 are radio buttons.

```
random.add(val);
Collections.shuffle(random);


r1.setText(random.get(0));
r2.setText(random.get(1));
r3.setText(random.get(2));
r4.setText(random.get(3));
```

I am able to display the answers in jumbled way but when i select the answer i need to show that the answer is correct or wrong.

```
Sample question and options.
1. which language is used for android programming?
 A.PHP
 B.JAVA
 C.C
 D.C++
```

Correct answer is B i need to display that correct answer is B.

How to acheive this.

**EDIT:**
I have tried this:

Onclick of each radio button assign the value A and compare the value with xml value if its correct display correct but when i jumble its will not work.

**EDIT 2**
xml

```
<Question no="1" text="Which Programming language is used in android develoment" type="SCA" noc="4" jumble="NO" correctans="PHP">
<choice a = "PHP" flag="A"> 
<choice b = "JAVA" flag="B"> 
<choice c = "C" flag="C"> 
<choice d = "C++" flag="D">
```

Comment: And what have you tried?

Comment: Please see i have edit in my question...

Comment: so when the answer is selected, what is difficulty to check if it is right or no?? put on clickLictener to radiobuttons and check results if it is right answer or no

Comment: @Daler but will we cannot compare the Strings. as in case in the answers is images then?

Comment: ok, here is how i see it, you have string in xml, ok, but you shuffle and assign them dynamically, why you also dont compare them in this way? For sure xml will not work anymore...

Comment: @Daler u are correct ... i am editing my question please see...

Comment: @Egor please see my question i have edited.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a somewhat naive solution but it should work.

```
class Question {
    String message;
    String answer;
    List<String> options; //"Java", "PHP", etc
}
```

Shuffle the keys of the Map in your Question object
In your radio buttons, do something like `r1.setText(random.get(0))`

On click, do

```
String choice = null;
for (RadioButton rb : rBtns) {
    if (rb.isSelected) {
        choice = rb.getText(); break();
    }
}

if (choice.equals(question.getAnswer))
    return true; //correct
else
    return false; //wrong
```

Answer (score 6):

You can create a hashmap with Option-isOptionCorrect pair. Like for your case:

```
HashMap<String, Boolean> choices = new HashMap<String, Boolean>();
choices.put("PHP", false);
choices.put("JAVA", true);
choices.put("C", false);
choices.put("C++", false);
```

Now shuffle the key-value pairs. Your correct choice will be one which has value `true` in the HashMap.

Answer (score 4):

Egor is clear for what he is suggesting but I'll let you work with your current implementations.

```
class Option{
      //You can add any other parameters if required.
      String optionText;
      boolean isAnswer;
}
```

// Use arraylist of Option class like this
`ArrayList<Option> options = new ArrayList<Option>();` // in your case random

// Now suffle it.
Collections.shuffle(options);
// get the user selected option and verify using.
if(options.get(userSelectedOptionPosition).isAnswer){
      //show "You are Correct!"
}else{
     // show "You are In correct!"
}

Hope this will help you.

Answer (score 2):

The best approach here is not to operate with `Strings`, but to create a `Question` class, which will contain all the info about a question: its value, list of answers and the index of the right answer. When parsing the XML, create a list of `Question` objects and then work with them. There won't be any mapping problems anymore. Hope this helps.

Comment: @Goofy, I hope you get the idea, cause the example will be a bit broad and unfortunately I can't write it for you now.

Comment: if u give me something coding logic that would really help me please it my request to you...

Comment: @Goofy, And didn't I give it? Create a class named Question with attributes described in XML; when parsing the XML, create objects of Question and populate them with XML values; use Question objects and their attributes everywhere you've previously used Strings; the rest will become clear if you follow these steps.

Answer (score 2):

You can hold your answers in your 'random' arraylist in a model, instead of pure strings;

```
private class AnswerModel {
    string answer;
    boolean flag;

//... getters and setters...
}
```

Here you can set your true answer' s flag to true, and all others to false. That way, you can simply return if the answer was correct.

Answer (score 1):

There are already several good answers here. But another option is to write your own shuffle function. The shuffle algorithm is a very simple algorithm that runs in linear time, at least for arrays. By writing your own shuffle function, you can keep track of where the correct answer ends up.

To make this simple, I'm posting code that returns the new index of a specified index in a shuffled collection. The function mutates (alters) the original collection, so this should work.

```
/**
 * @return Returns the new index of the element that was placed at correctIndex,
 *         or -1 if the correctIndex parameter was out of bounds.
 */
public int shuffleAnswers(Collection<String> collection, index correctIndex) {
    String[] shuffleArray = new String[collection.size()];
    int returnValue = -1;

    collection.toArray(shuffleArray); // Convert to array
    collection.clear(); // We have to add the elements again later

    // Pick random elements
    for (int i = shuffleArray.length; i > 0; i--) {
        int randIndex = Math.random() * i;
        if (returnValue == -1 && randIndex == correctIndex) {
            // This only works if elements are added to the end
            // So you may want to limit the function to ArrayLists or LinkedLists
            returnValue = collection.size();
        }

        // Add the randomly selected element to the collection
        collection.add(shuffleArray[randIndex]);

        // We must ensure that we don't lose elements
        // So we swap them down from the end
        shuffleArray[randIndex] = shuffleArray[i - 1];
    }

    return returnValue;
}
```

Note like the comments say, this only works with collections that add elements to the end of the collection, and that fills arrays from the first to last element added to the collection.

This is perhaps slower than the other solutions, but note that you require a shuffle anyway, so it shouldn't affect running speed much.

Answer (score 1):

Another option is just to have a `correctAnswer` String and then compare the user's choice to the string (with `.equals()`).

Answer (score 0):

This is what would I do.
Since you are remembering answer in your XML file and not answers position, then on selected radio button take text (in this case it would be "PHP", "Java", "C++" or "C") and compare it with correct answer.

Jumbling can't affect on this, otherwise you are doing something wrong.